# Objective-C: Why I am getting exception trying to remove object from nsmutable array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I thought what I am trying to do is really basic stuffs, I have 2 NSMutableArrays that contains MyItem objects. I want to remove the item from one array and add it to another array but it throws exception when trying to remove it and Yes to save you a complain, my understanding of fundamental OOP is a failure. I am not even dealing with enumerate thru array at all.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    MyItem *item = [self.completedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

    if(![self.toDoItems containsObject: item])
        [self.toDoItems addObject: item];

    if([self.completedItems containsObject: item])
        [self.completedItems removeObject:item];

    [self.tableView reloadData]; //reload contents on table view controller
}
```

Here is the exception

[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d8bba0

here is how the arrays are loaded. it is array of dictionaries basically.

```
@interface ToDoListTableViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (strong) NSMutableArray *completedItems;
    @property (strong) NSMutableArray *toDoItems;  
@end

self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //initialize array
self.completedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //initialize array

 MyItem *newItem = [[MyItem alloc] init];
            newItem.text = [item valueForKey:@"text"];
            newItem.completed = [[item valueForKey:@"completed"] boolValue];
            newItem.date = [item valueForKey:@"date"];

            if (newItem.completed) {
                [self.completedItems addObject: newItem];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.toDoItems addObject: newItem];
            }
```

EDIT
Maybe this code somehow makes the destination arrays to become Immutable ones?

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
CompleteTableViewController *objChild = (CompleteTableViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

if(objChild != nil){
     objChild.completedItems =  [self.completedItems copy];
     objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems copy];
}
```

Thanks in advance for point out my issue.

Comment: What exception?  Quote it exactly.

Comment: Is self.completedItems a mutableArray?

Comment: You should double-check that array is in fact mutable, which is not obvious from your code, just having a pointer to mutable array does not make it so. For example if you have dictionary, under it array, and you make mutable copy of dictionary , the sub object - array  will still be immutable ... so how do you get your items loaded into self.toDoItems ? , in debugger "po self.toDoItems" should tell you it's class. Also make sure you are not removing nil object, that results in exception.

Comment: @Qiqi Ah,that shed some lights. self.completedItems is declared as NSMutableArray. I edited the original post to supplied some more info

Comment: If you're declaring it as an NSMutableArray, are you also initializing it as an NSMutableArray?

Comment: You still aren't showing where you are creating your `completedItems` array.

Comment: @Logan, yes I am updating post to show how they init

Comment: Objective-C is "duck typed". This means that if it looks like a duck and walks like a duck and quacks like a duck it's a duck, regardless of the name you hang on it.  You have a variable that may be declared NSMutableArray, but the object in it looks, walks, and quacks like an NSArray -- because that's what's you created and that's what's actually stored in the variable.

Comment: Is there no other place where you set `completedItems`?

Comment: @Hot Licks, so which part of my code do you think looks like duck so I can make it work like the name it wear? - Thanks

Comment: What we know is that at the point that "[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector" occurred you were operating on an NSArray, not an NSMutableArray.  You need to work backwards from there to figure out how this happened.  I'd first look at all references to "completedItems" (use Xcode's search facilities) to make sure you're not assigning something to the variable without knowing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you were reassigning the data to your property as an immutable object

```
if(objChild != nil){
 objChild.completedItems =  [self.completedItems copy];
 objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems copy];
}
```

if you want it to be mutable, you should use:

```
if(objChild != nil){
 objChild.completedItems =  [self.completedItems mutableCopy];
 objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: YOU NAILED IT GIRL. I will give you 100 points if I have that ability- I overlook at this, I didn't know there is different kind of copy. thanks!

Comment: +1  The convention for the mutable/immutable pattern is that `-copy` returns an **immutable** object.

Answer (score 4):

As the exception points out `self.completedItems` is an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`. `NSArray` has no such method `removeObject`.

Update! There's the problem code!

```
if(objChild != nil){
     objChild.completedItems =  [self.completedItems copy]; //should be mutableCopy
     objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems copy]; //should be mutableCopy
}
```

Comment: This is why it's so important to include the exception message.

Comment: @Hot I realized that I edit it immediately, but you are just faster than I was, which is great!

Answer (score 1):

that is why you get exception:

```
if (objChild != nil) {
    // INCORRECT immutable copy, aka NSArray
    objChild.completedItems =  [self.completedItems copy]; 
    objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems copy];
}
```

the code above should look like:

```
if (objChild != nil) {
    // CORRECT mutable copy, aka NSMutableArray
    objChild.completedItems =  [self.completedItems mutableCopy];
    objChild.toDoItems =  [self.toDoItems mutableCopy];
}
```

---

because it happens in runtime the compiler is not able to warn you, therefore you got the crash only.

Comment: anytime, someone was faster than me, but you have the solution finally. :)

Comment: You are incorrect. The compiler doesn't warn you because an NSMutableArray IS an NSArray. NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. This has nothing to do with the runtime.

Comment: no the compiler didnt care that I was doing a dumb thing. it just vomited when looking at my code I guess.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, I'm not really sure who was the target of your comment here... because my anwser says: _the compiler **is not able** to warn you_, and ___it happens__ in runtime_, which pretty much means literally _in runtime_. it seems you have misread something here, or you are just the wrong way...

Comment: What I meant to say was that since `copy` returns an `id`, you can assign it to anything without getting a compiler warning. I had it backwards in my earlier comment, I thought he was assigning a NSMutableArray to an NSArray reference, which the compiler would be okay with.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, yes, and your assumption has been clearly written in this answer. according this, I do not really see the reason of your very first comment... you are just saying the same thing, starting with "you are incorrect". I don't see the reason of debate here.

Answer (score 0):

__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d8bba0  ,
this tells you that your array is not mutable ArrayI (array immutable), please double-check what you have loaded into property. Nothing stops you from loading NSNumber,NSString,NSArray to be loaded into property where you expect type of NSMutableArray, so then you are ready for a nasty surprise...